# Shorthand if/else php not continue

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-5

How to get to the next argument event if the second or third is false ? in my case `gender` is `false` but `marital status` is `true` but they stop at `gender` and not execute `marital status`. how can I make it continue to next argument event second or third is `false` ?

```
public function creditScore($user, $basic_information)
    {
        $basic_information->birth_date ? dispatch(new CalculateAge($user)) : false;
        $basic_information->dependents ? dispatch(new CalculateDependents($user)) : false;
        $basic_information->education ? dispatch(new CalculateEducation($user)) : false;
        $basic_information->gender ? dispatch(new CalculateGender($user)) : false;
        $basic_information->marital_status ? dispatch(new CalculateMaritalStatus($user)) : false;
    }
```

Comment: That's not a shorthand if, that's the [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: I'd also add that the ternary operator looks weird in this scenario, since `false` is never used. I'd prefer if-statements.

Comment: thanks for answering my question Im just learn php I didnt know if that was ternary operator @simon

Comment: @OlleHärstedt Im just make it simple to read not many if else just one line code but I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if (isset($basic_information->birth_date)) dispatch(new CalculateAge($user));
```

Comment: `$basic_information->gender` is set but Im calling event for the result and result false so they not execute next argument